# setup.sh uses rm without -f: errors on login/new shell

Tags: ros, setup.sh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have defined:
alias rm='rm -i'
to prevent myself from desasters.

Unfortunately ROS setup.sh uses rm in a way, that I get asked to remove the file /tmp/setup.sh.XXXXX while logging in or starting a new bash (both source setup.sh).

Well, here is a patch, that adds a check and some quotes, too:

```
$ diff /opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh.orig /opt/ros/groovy/setup.sh
37,41c37,45
< MKTEMP=`which mktemp`
< SETUP_TMP=`$MKTEMP /tmp/setup.sh.XXXXXXXXXX`
< $SETUP_UTIL $@ > $SETUP_TMP
< . $SETUP_TMP
< rm $SETUP_TMP
---
> MKTEMP="`which mktemp`"
> SETUP_TMP="`$MKTEMP /tmp/setup.sh.XXXXXXXXXX`"
> if [ $? -ne 0 ] ;  then
>   echo "ROS config error: creating tmp file for setup failed" >> "/dev/stderr"
> else
>  $SETUP_UTIL $@ > "$SETUP_TMP"
>  . "$SETUP_TMP"
>  rm -f "$SETUP_TMP"
> fi
```

might be worth a patch, but unfortunately I was not able to create an account on the bugtracker.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53777/setup.sh-uses-rm-without--f:-errors-on-login/new-shell/) by [Martin.W](https://answers.ros.org/users/2124/martin.w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ticket created:
github.com/ros/catkin/issues/343

---

Originally posted by [Martin.W](https://answers.ros.org/users/2124/martin.w/) with karma: 16 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0